# how to install pip in python3.5 on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I followed a video online and tried to download pip using terminal, but it doesn't work. It showed a path of python2.7, but I am actually using python3.5, is it the problem?
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Try  run command `python3`, `python3.5`?

Comment: you may have conflicting python installations.. ensure python2.7 is completely uninstalled

Comment: `python3.5 -mpip install pip --upgrade`

Comment: @Kevin Guan Thank you for your response, when I used "python3", it showed"Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages", but when I try"sudo pip-install requests", it still showed"sudo: pip-install: command not found"

Answer (score -1):

The most simple way is to use OS X package manager called `brew`.
Install brew from your console:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And after:

```
brew install python3.5
```

or

```
brew install python3
```

Comment: I Perform above step and i got following error


➜  Python-3.5.6 brew install python3.5
Error: No available formula with the name "python3.5" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...